# Can't login using ssh as root

Tags: ssh, login, root

I am trying to virtualize an old linux server, and the PtoV software requires a password login as root via ssh. However, the root login is being prevented with a "*Permission Denied*" error on the client end, and a "*Failed Password for root*" on the server end (when sshd is running in debug mode).

I HAVE set `PermitRootLogin yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

This is an old RedHat 7.3 server that has had hardening scripts like Bastille run on it years and years ago, and has many remnants of old OS's (like ipchains - no longer supported by the kernel) lying around. All to say I have little idea what has been altered from the original system, but there is a lot.

- I can log in fine as root from the console
- I can su to root fine from within the console or ssh session
- I can ssh fine as a regular user.

My question is: **What else could be preventing my root login** on this server?

More information:
/etc/pam.d/sshd

```
 auth       required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
 auth       required     pam_nologin.so
 account    required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
 password   required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
 session    required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
 session    required     pam_limits.so
 session    optional     pam_console.so
```

/etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
auth        required      /lib/security/pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    /lib/security/pam_unix.so likeauth nullok
auth        required      /lib/security/pam_deny.so
account     required      /lib/security/pam_unix.so
password    required      /lib/security/pam_cracklib.so retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    /lib/security/pam_unix.so nullok use_authtok md5 shadow
password    required      /lib/security/pam_deny.so
session     required      /lib/security/pam_limits.so
session     required      /lib/security/pam_unix.so
```

---

Can anybody tell me if the hashing algorithm could be the culprit?  Keeping in mind that I can log in as an unprivileged user.

Comment: Check the SSH log to see if it sheds any info? Also the auth log if your system has one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the /etc/init.d/sshd script had no $OPTIONS variable, which would be the reference to the config file.  Therefore sshd was starting without any config file at all, and hence, defaulting to "PermitRoodLogin no".

I resolved this by adding the following line near the start of /etc/init.d/sshd:

```
OPTIONS="-f /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: Thanks, you saved a life today!!

Answer (score 2):

Login as root via ssh could be disabled in the PAM configuration.

Comment: Okay, I don't really understand PAM - is it possible to configure sshd to ignore PAM?  (note, I tried a working sshd_config file from another machine, and it contained "UsePAM yes" - but sshd didn't recognize that directive)

Comment: Ignoring PAM is almost always the wrong thing to do. Look in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to see if anything stands out.

Comment: Doesn't appear to, but I have posted the relevant pam configs.  Does anything stand out to you?

Comment: No, that all looks perfectly normal and non-root-blocking.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I can authenticate with any user but when I'm trying with root I get this message "access denied".  The problem was solved by disabling `UsePAM yes` in
 `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Change `UsePAM yes` to `#UsePAM yes`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what Ignacio said, I'm guessing you are using pam_securetty and the ttys aren't in `/etc/securetty`. I don't recall what the tty names are in RH7.3. Ssh in as a normal user and run `who` to see the naming system.

Comment: Okay - tty1 and tty2. go on...  (these ARE listed in /etc/securetty)

Comment: Oops - I was wrong.  They are pts/0, pts/1, etc.  I have added those entries to /etc/securetty, but to no avail. I am still being blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from embobo, I happily (!) have a big cluster of RH73 boxes I'm not allowed to upgrade.  They tell me that remote logins are on `pts/0`, `pts/1`, `pts/2` and so on.

Could you try adding those to `/etc/securetty` and see if that improves matters?  Probably best to add them as far as (say) pts/9, depending on how many other users are usually logged in.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I mis-read the output of who - they ARE pts/0, pts/1, etc.  Unfortunately, adding those and restarting ssh didn't resolve the situation.  Can you explain what /etc/securetty does?

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`?

Comment: Yes, I posted them above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the questions and responses, helped me narrow things down.
In my particular case I had already allowed root login.
I found running sshd with console messages useful.
Stop the service daemon

```
systemctl stop sshd
```

Run it with console messages enabled

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -De -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

When done just CTRL+C and start the service as normal.

The final component was caught in watching the logs and not seeing the transaction reach the daemon. Firewall/iptables looked fine but security hardening had been added using hosts.allow/deny.

/etc/hosts.deny:
`sshd:ALL`
/etc/hosts.allow:
`sshd:10.10.10., 192.168.8.`

Adding the IP for my conversion utility box here let it process and then observed a log entry

```
User root from 10.10.62.10 not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
```

Added root to the wheel group and success. Hope this helps the next person.